# LocationRequest smallest displacement and accuracy

Tags: android, geolocation, location, google-play-services

I'm building an Android app in which I need to have a very accurate location at a very high frequency.
I dove into google play services api for location, and found the LocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement very useful to limit battery consumption.

However, as I am testing it indoor, the locations I get have an accuracy that varies a lot (sometimes 10m, sometimes 96m...), even when I set the Priority of my request as high accuracy.

My prob1em is that setSmallestDisplacement doesn't give a sh*it about the accuracy that is returned last.
So if I get a location with a very low accuracy, I will still have to walk my "smallest displacement" distance to get a new one, hopefully more accuracte.

I wonder if there is a way to avoid such data (I can't use location that are not accurate enough) or if I have to skip the setSmallestDisplacement part (bad for battery consumption).

Some code for your pleasure:

```
mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
mLocationRequest.setInterval(100); //We get a new location every 100ms or so
//mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(5);  //but only if we traveled 5m
mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please post an answer if you find out any solution for this.

Comment: What kind of device you are testing on - WiFi-only or data+Wifi?

Comment: Agreed. What use would getting a location with even smallest displacement 100m, if the location comes from a cell tower with accuracy 3000m.

Comment: In what direction you travelled?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "LocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement" doesn't matter for accuracy, it's just to avoid unnecessary updates, you can continuing using that.

There is no method to enhance low accuracy, you just get a point with some accuracy (better or worse), if you are not interested on positions with low accuracy just skip this location and wait for a better one.

This page could help you about accuracy and consumption, but take in mind no perfect accuracy exist, with Wi-Fi the accuracy is 100m for worse accuracy.

Here you have the accuracy for each priority.
https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html#location-request

Here the IO Session from Google engineers, very useful, you can get the PDF there too.
<strike>https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/325337477</strike>

**Updated Links brokens**

The [PDF Presentation](http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/io-2013/presentations/106%20-%20Beyond%20the%20Blue%20Dot-%20New%20features%20in%20Android%20Location%20(1).pdf)

The [IO session](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=URcVZybzMUI)

Hope this helps :D.

Comment: Well it was a long time ago and I don't work on this project anymore, but your answer does bring some light on the subject. thx!

Comment: Not sure I see how this helped. Questioner wanted to get locations that were less than smallestdisplacement away if they are more accurate. Unless I misunderstood?

Comment: the IO session link is broken, can you update it or provide its name & year ?

Comment: @MidasLefko Please read more mindful! "if you are not interested on positions with low accuracy just skip this location and wait for a better one"